# Get fields with one relation

Tags: propel

```
test:
  _attributes:   { phpName: Test }
  name:    { type: varchar, size: 100 }
  one_id:  { type: INTEGER, foreignTable: second, foreignReference: id}
  two_id:  { type: INTEGER, foreignTable: second, foreignReference: id}


second:
  _attributes:   { phpName: Second }
  name:          { type: varchar, size: 100 }
```

In Doctrine I can get this with `$test->getSecond1();` and `$test->getSecond2();` but in Propel this doesnt work. How can I get two other fields from one relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the right associated object, when we have two foreign references to the same foreign table, we need to use:

```
$test->getSecondRelatedByOneId()
$test->getSecondRelatedByTwoId()
```

Then we get foreign references to `Second` in `Test` object with:

```
$test->getOneId()
$test->getTwoId()
```

I use only Propel at the moment, so sorry if I misunderstood.